# Hold-on-hold-off soft latch power switch circuit

Tags: switches, latch, falstad

I'm trying to make a "hold-on-hold-off" type soft latch switch circuit, but I'm having a little trouble. I've found tons of "press-on-hold-off" types, but I haven't been able to find a single example of a "hold-on" type anywhere.

I found/have been experimenting with [this example](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch#press-on-hold-off-latching-circuits) "press-on-hold-off" circuit, and have a working model in [Falstad circuit simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0lwrOATLekmQMwA4xKQCxjYCciaIiBmlApgLRhgBQY8E2B24BBIJSbmF5QQSUfFbsQAdnjiwANkghsmBctHjyzAO6r14TZyGbIe1V2TcT4PFGYBjWYqH3Xb8SphxfEeNAE%20ISQ1LxIMkgkBPAMTFCwkCwATpaeaSBWKmC%20cBYyrnbitkxezKmKBNnuVZnc2bnm%20h5FIJXVZfq2Vu11Ds4yoWKQ3IN8wnzeiX4g9ATQJItLy%20wkmDIJcCz6cgoiYzyTFgJCItHjIk38IhPXfBj1xyIPsvLDjztvL7vgBQ6pB1uvVuKjQjQswJEwPsVwOL16LyuwM0kKOAHNZENvljCKJzAAlNq1Hq1byiWqIMkwSRKcTnQ7gOCne4gAAmtAAZgBDACuABsAC70Pm0VngPGbFgYnIjBkyoR-bzMADOROyKNqiPFAuSPNozAA9oyieTICRuJToBAVAoVJhmEA):

[image: falstad sim]

I was wondering if there was a simple way to modify it to work as a hold-on type. I thought maybe another capacitor could be added at the switch to act as a "debounce", making it take longer to turn on, but that hasn't worked in the simulator, so I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding how the circuit works, or if my idea is just wrong.

Any thoughts or wisdom would be appreciated.

Comment: Is using a microcontroller out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is poorly formed.  What holds it on and what holds it off?  In falstad or the real world?  What power levels?  ac or DC?  What starts it?  Forever?  Do you want a controllable switch?

For the circuit you show, try an analog switch.  You can then control how you want.  In this case, falstad does have analog switches.

When the switch is closed, it is held closed until LED turns OFF.  Switch is opened and held open until counter counts to 0x80 at 40Hz.  Repeat.

[image]

[Falstad Circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0lwrOATLekmQMwA4xKQCxjYCciaIiBmlApgLRhgBQY8E2B24BBIJSbmF5QQSSpVbsQAdnjiwANkghsmBctHiV8ZgHdV68Js5DNkfaq7Jup8HijMAxrMVCHb99qiw4cCATQJDLEMgLwmOhwNDD%20zABOVl5JINYqYH5wljJu9uJ2TNoJIIoE6R5lqdzpmRYGnnkllYWOBnbWpSppzrKQfBjcMn08fCqxmRD0mNBIaDIE8LyQJATBCz5xBnIKIkN8wqOWAkIiK-sidfwiB1f9kNVHIgOy8mL3rS-iz9vgOY6JexGTXSF0otUunSBkJal0Bz0hzwhzU00IuzAA5r07oNhvhRo4AErAqrEsaiSqIMkwXRKcRnIEZd43cQAE1oADMAIYAVwANgAXei82gs8CiMawFiYxknfZwIR-MZSEjEpQqaECLQ1cF%20SwI94aooGRb9GTiE2-RQfC1gP6KQiWxxKPiKeBW9Tqs0gD0lG7VcUBqkgLm8gDOtEJJWw3BwLujqSMKnEFMD0F09Uqsyt0aTbo%20JAcsdu3s4%20ZERfpWadrwRXvgfyQXqTEnTxME3Aa7etDbrTybj2xxarlxzYjzlbzFgA9uB1fiyiQhBKIM2Mt7mEA)